# How to transfer sound from my windows 10 PC to a wifi speaker?

Tags: wireless-router, speakers

I bought 2 Harman Kardon Omni 10. I want to use it as a wireless PC speaker.

The speakers have several ways to get data. Cable, bluetooth and wifi. I wonder how can I transfer sound from my PC to the wireless speaker with wifi. The PC and the harman kardon speakers are on the same home network.

Is that even possible?

Comment: You only have two choices.  Connect the device to your PC via `Bluetooth` or the `3.5mm mini-jack`.

Comment: I used bluetooth. The quality sucks with things go really wrong. 3.5mm mini jack is an alternative but not "cool"

Comment: My phone can play music via wifi and my PC cannot?

Answer (score 1):

It's been six months so I hope you've figured this one out already. However what I did was purchase an Adapt (harman kardon) and plug it into one of the outputs of my office computer. On the computer I set it up as a stereo pair of front speakers. That way I can setup a playlist at the desktop and send it around the house.

Another option is to plug a chromecast audio dongle into the speaker and broadcast that way. I found a program called Airparrot that helps with that but it's a bit buggy so the adapt is my go to.

Comment: It seems that anything involving wifi will cause significant sound delay.